# VSTO 2010 - How do I take and save attachments or messages from Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

Long story short - I am creating a tool with VSTO to digitally archive documents as PDFs and automatically sort them into the appropriate folders. With a Microsoft Word 2010 add-in, I have achieved the exact result I wanted but now I have to adapt this to work with Outlook 2010 also.

In Word I can refer to my active document via

```
doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
```

and setting the file format, I use

```
FileFormat = WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF;
```

to which I save via

```
doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(Name.ToString(), WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false, WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForPrint, WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 0, 0, WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentContent, false, false, WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, false, true, true, ref FixedFormatExtClassPtr);
```

---

I imagine Outlook would be quite different since I must consider:

1. Defining the active email (which I would imagine being quite similar in syntax to `ActiveDocument`)
2. Checking whether or not there is an attachment
3. The number of attachments in the email
4. The format of said attachments and whether or I can convert them to PDF
5. If it is possible to save the email contents also

---

If any of the above can be answered/solved then I would be immensely grateful. Thank you

*(I am very new to Stack Overflow and as far as I am aware this question follows the rules that I have read on the site. If it does not, can you politely let me know please and I will remove it)*

Answer (score 1):

I can give you answer to some of your questions not all.

1  - if you want to get selected item(s) then use

```
var ex =  Application.ActiveExplorer;
var selected = ex.Selection
```

if you want to get opened item then use

```
var opened = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem;
```

2 & 3 - the above will return MailItem object(s) and it has a property called Attachments so you can check if there is any

4 - you can certainly try to check extension of all attachment and decide but I'm not sure what exactly you mean here

5 - Definitely, the MailItem object has also Body property so you can get all the text

Probably the hard part will be saving to PDF I don't know how to do that if it's e.g. an image

Comment: Thank you, it has been immensely difficult to find much help on this subject so you have given me a great starting point to build this. What I meant by number 4 is perhaps I could find a way to determine the file format of the attachment and do an if or switch to decide what to do with this attachment so my main issue there would be determining what the file format is or if I can pick the part of the filename that has ".jpg" or ".docx" etc